# OAuth 2.0 provider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth-2.0, wcf-web-api

Does someone knows OAuth 2.0 provider (server) written in ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: check this article and the download link: http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/18/oauth-2-0-for-mvc-two-legged-implementation.aspx

Comment: This is great, but I need three legged implementation...

Comment: I was looking for the exact same thing recently and all I could find were a couple, one written in ruby the other in php. So, we decided to wait a while :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Providers:**

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

[Azure ACS](http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples&referringTitle=Documentation)

**Consumers:**

Look at [that  project](https://github.com/antimony/OhAuthToo) and [that article](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2011/10/11/oauth-2-0-in-web-api/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20CodeBetter%20%28CodeBetter.Com%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I need OAuth 2.0 provider not consumer code.

Comment: dotnetopenauth.net support OAuth 2 in CTP http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/

Comment: Azure ACS also supports OAuth 2.0

http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 1):

Here is you can get clear description for this concept. Here you can get more info on MVC 4/MVC 5 realted information.

http://onlinedotnet.com/what-is-oauth-in-mvc-oauth2-in-mvc-5/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.